# The sidebar appears to be under attack by a merciless, giant, mutant Gravatar

Tags: bug, chat, sidebar

[image: EEEK!]

OH GOD IT'S ALREADY CONSUMED TIM AND IT'S COMING FOR ME WHAT DO I DO?

<sub>Mouseover tooltip indicates that it belongs to AHSteele, and this is occurring to me using Safari 5.1.5 under OS X 10.7</sub>

Comment: This has happened a few times in the past few months.  IIRC it was Gravatar issue, they serve up the wrong size image sometimes or something.  If that's the case here I'd still say SE should only display one corner of the image or something.

Comment: This is clearly @spugsley's doing.